# Streaming with VLC returns socket bind error (Permission denied) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vlc

I'm trying to stream an .mkv file using VLC on Ubuntu 12.04, but keep receiving:

```
[http] main interface error: socket bind error (Permission denied)
```

I have the next setting for VLC:

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled
setup channel1 input /tmp/recording40.mkv
setup channel1 output #http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/live1}
setup channel1 option http-reconnect
setup channel1 option no-sout-rtp-sap option no-sout-standard-sap
option ttl=1 option sout-keep

control channel1 play
```

And running vlc with:

```
nohup cvlc -Ihttp --file-logging --log-verbose=1 --logfile="vlc.log" --vlm-conf vlm.conf & echo $! > vlc.pid
```

As you can see I'm using port 8080, so non-root user should have access to open that port. I have also tried other ports too - no luck. Running cvlc with root doesn't help either (and that is not recommended by the documentation).

Any ideas why I keep receiving this error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer my own question.

So as it turns out it didn't matter what port I speficied in the above config file the http port vlc is trying to use is always 8080, where I already had socket.io running.

The only way to change the port is actually by using the --http-port= parameter when calling cvlc:

```
nohup cvlc -Ihttp --file-logging --log-verbose=1 --logfile="vlc.log" --http-port=9090 --vlm-conf vlm.conf & echo $! > vlc.pid
```